# Jenkins Post Build Task does not work when job is aborted

Tags: jenkins, post-build-event

I have an issue about Post Build Task after an job abort (manual or timeout): the abort generates a java.lang.InterruptedException which seems to be normal. But as Jenkins java machine is stucked how can you run a post task script? I can't.

here is the java exception:

```
#174 aborted
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(Native Method)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:319)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:345)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:82)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:58)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
at 
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:710)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:178)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:139)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:480)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1438)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)
```

Here is my jenkins output:

```
Build was aborted
Aborted by admin
Performing Post build task...
Match found for :. : True
Logical operation result is TRUE
Running script  : dir 
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local
\Temp\2hudson5872719646331136420.bat
Exception when executing the batch command : null
Build step 'Post build task' marked build as failure
Finished: ABORTED
```

I ran a bat script on the server that copied all hudson****.bat from the folder (which is cleaned after the job) during the job execution/aborting so I've been able to run cmd /c call C:\xxxx\hudson5872719646331136420.bat manually from the windows run, it worked fine.

thanks for your help

Comment: You want to run a post-build step when there is no build?

Comment: As I searched on the web a solution to launch a script after a build regardless of build execution (success,failed,aborted) I found that this plugin would do the job:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/lQe7G5xFDww

http://tiku.io/questions/2861609/running-a-post-build-script-when-a-jenkins-job-is-aborted

Comment: Sure. But assuming you use some data from the build, and those data are not written  because of that abort, it will never work out - but usually it will.

Comment: I don't use any data from the build in the post build task script which is fully independant of what is execute (or not) before. In the case of a build failure, it works fine. My guess was that my environment was in a "locked like" state as the jvm crashed so jenkins was not able to launch the script.

Comment: Ok, sorry - I presumed that because of the "Exception when executing the batch command : null"

Comment: I get more informations, I create a bat script on the jenkins server that lists files in a inifinite loop the folderC:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local
\Temp\2, run my job and abort it, the temp bat file generated by jenkins during the post build task is never written on this folder, so obviously this is the reason why it doesn't work, but this file is not written, I still can't get the answer by myself

Comment: If I understand correctly you want a batch file to run, but Jenkins doesn't find it. Did you try to enter the command just in Jenkins, in stead of trying to upload it?

Comment: Yes I tried, same result. In fact, Jenkins seems to create a temp bat file to execute the  command (whether it is in a batch file or enter in Jenkins GUI). This  temp file is written in the java.io.tmpdir. I managed to copy it before delted, ran it manually and it worked fine. My guess is that Java deleted it, due to the abort interruptedException, before jenkins run it

Comment: I found another solution to do what I want with post build groovy scripts that works perfectly fine. It appears that the issue that I encountered withe the post build task plugin has been encountered by many Jenkins user. Maybe the plugin is not maintained since a long time.